# Improving BERT by training on additional data

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I have a BERT multilanguage model from Google. And I have a lot of text data in my language (Korean). I want BERT to make better vectors for texts in this language. So I want to additionally train BERT on that text corpus I have. Like if I would have w2v model trained on some data and would want to continue training it. Is it possible with BERT?

There are a lot of examples of "fine-tuning" BERT on some specific tasks like even the [original one from Google](https://github.com/google-research/bert#fine-tuning-with-bert) where you can train BERT further on your data. But as far as I understand it (I might be wrong) we do it within our task-specified model (for classification task for example). So... we do it at the same time as training our classifier (??)

What I want is to train BERT further separately and then get fixed vectors for my data. Not to build it  into some task-specified model. But just get vector representation for my data (using get_features function) like they do in [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/nlp-extract-contextualized-word-embeddings-from-bert-keras-tf-67ef29f60a7b). I just need to train the BERT model additionally on more data of the specific language.

Would be endlessly grateful for any suggestions/links on how to train BURT model further (preferably Tensorflow). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Package [`transformers`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) provides code for using and fine-tuning of most currently popular pre-trained Transformers including BERT, XLNet, GPT-2, ... You can easily load the model and continue training.

You can get the multilingual BERT model:

```py
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-multiligual-cased')
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-multiligual-cased')
```

The tokenizer is used both for tokenizing the input and for converting the sub-words into embedding ids. Calling the model on the subword indices will give you hidden states of the model.

Unfortunately, the package does not implement the training procedure, i.e., the masked language model and the next sentence prediction. You will need to write it yourself, but the training procedure well described in the paper and the implementation will be straightforward.